# xcode info.plist build variable ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} seems completely undocumented?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, rfc1034identifier

I'm trying to find documentation that describe the syntax and possibilities suggested by the construction `${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`. Obviously this turns into some version of the product name, but where is the documentation that describes how? I just grepped the entire /Developer directory, and got nothing useful.

**I'm not looking for the narrow definition of what happens to this particular variable, I want to know about all such *modifiers* like `rfc1034identifier`.**

Comment: This might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468176/should-the-rfc1034identifier-be-removed-from-the-cfbundleidentifier-in-plist-file/2468382#2468382

Comment: I'm really looking for a formal definition. It makes me feel very nervous to be using things as if they were magic.

Comment: Are you sure the ":" is a modifier and not just another character in the macro name?  Where is the list of legal characters?

Comment: That's what I'm asking. Among other things.

Comment: Filed a developer issue with Apple.

Comment: Filed a bug with Apple, since the DTS person couldn't find and documentation either. https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/9/wo/KH4SJ0c6l97laT7FC9Vigw/10.60

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At long last, Apple produced some documentation on this. This is in the "Text Macros" section of the Xcode manual, as of this date.

## Text macro format reference

A text macro can contain any valid unicode text. It can also contain other text macros.

**Including other text macros**
To include another text macro, add three underscore (_) characters before and after the macro name:

```
___<MacroName>___
```

**Modifying text macro expansion**
You can modify the final expansion of the text macro by adding one or more modifiers. Add a modifier to a text macro by placing a colon (:) at the end of the macro followed by the modifier. Add multiple modifiers by separating each one with a comma (,).

```
<MACRO>:<modifier>[,<modifier>]…
```

For example, the following macro will remove the path extension from the FILENAME macro:

```
FILENAME:deletingPathExtension
```

To turn the modified macro above into a valid C identifier, add the identifier macro:

```
FILENAME:deletingPathExtension,identifier
```

### Modifiers

**bundleIdentifier**: Replaces any non-bundle identifier characters with a hyphen (-).

**deletingLastPathComponent**: Removes the last path component from the expansion string.

**deletingPathExtension**: Removes any path extension from the expansion string.

**deletingTrailingDot**: Removes any trailing dots (.).

**identifier**: Replaces any non-C identifier characters with an underscore (_).

**lastPathComponent**: Returns just the last path component of the expansion string.

**pathExtension**: Returns the path extension of the expansion string.

**rfc1034Identifier**: Replaces any non-rfc1034 identifier characters with a hyphen (-).

**xml**: Replaces special xml characters with the corresponding escape string. For example, less-than (<) is replaced with `&lt;`

## TEXT MACROS

Text macros reference

**COPYRIGHT**
A copyright string that uses the company name of the team for the project. If there is no company name, the string is blank.

The example shows a copyright string when the company is set to “Apple”.

Copyright © 2018 Apple. All rights reserved.

**DATE**
The current date.

**DEFAULTTOOLCHAINSWIFTVERSION**
The version of Swift used for the default toolchain.

**FILEBASENAME**
The name of the current file without any extension.

**FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER**
The name of the current file encoded as a C identifier.

**FILEHEADER**
The text placed at the top of every new text file.

**FILENAME**
The full name of the current file.

**FULLUSERNAME**
The full name of the current macOS user.

**NSHUMANREADABLECOPYRIGHTPLIST**
The entry for the human readable copyright string in the Info.plist file of a macOS app target. The value of the macro must include the XML delimiters for the plist. For example, a valid value is:

```
'''
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>

    <string>Copyright © 2018 Apple, Inc. All rights reserved.</string>


'''
```

Notice that the value includes a newline.

**ORGANIZATIONNAME**
The name for your organization that appears in boilerplate text throughout your project folder. The organization name in your project isn’t the same as the organization name that you enter in App Store Connect.

**PACKAGENAME**
The name of the package built by the current scheme.

**PACKAGENAMEASIDENTIFIER**
A C-identifier encoded version of the package name built by the current scheme.

**PRODUCTNAME**
The app name of the product built by the current scheme.

**PROJECTNAME**
The name of the current project.

**RUNNINGMACOSVERSION**
The version of macOS that is running Xcode.

**TARGETNAME**
The name of the current target.

**TIME**
The current time.

**USERNAME**
The login name for the current macOS user.

**UUID**
Returns a unique ID. The first time this macro is used, it generates the ID before returning it. You can use this macro to create multiple unique IDs by using a modifier. Each modifier returns an ID that is unique for that modifier. For example, the first time the UUID:firstPurpose modifier is used, the macro generates and returns a unique ID for that macro and modifier combination. Subsequent uses of the UUID:firstPurpose modifier return the same ID. Adding the UUID:secondPurpose modifier generates and returns a different ID that will be unique to UUID:secondPurpose, and different from the ID for UUID:firstPurpose.

**WORKSPACENAME**
The name of the current workspace. If there is only one project open, then the name of the current project.

**YEAR**
The current year as a four-digit number.

Answer (score 33):

By using `strings` I also dug out the following things that look like they're related to `:rfc1034identifier`:

- `:quote` - adds backslashes before whitespaces (and more), for use in shell scripts
- `:identifier` - replaces whitespace, slashes (and more) with underscores
- `:rfc1034identifier` - replaces whitespace, slashes (and more) with dashes
- `:dir` - don't know, observed replace with `./` in some cases
- `:abs` - don't know

Exact command:

```
strings /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsCore|grep '^:'
```

There are more things that look like interesting modifiers (for example, `:char-range=%@`), but I couldn't get these to work. There's only one example of `:char-range` on the net, and it's from a crash log for Xcode.

Someone asked how do we know it's a modifier specification. Well, we know because it works on multiple variables in build settings. Plist preprocessor probably uses the same mechanisms to resolve build variables as does the build system.

Hack Saw, if you get a response via that bug report, don't forget to keep us informed :-)

Comment: I certainly will. Thanks for your investigation!

Comment: WHen using stand alone `Xcode.app`, the path is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/OtherFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsCore`

Comment: http://codeworkshop.net/posts/xcode-build-setting-transformations looks like it has some helpful explanations.

Answer (score 13):

Looks like you can stack these as well. The useful case [floating around out](https://twitter.com/maxbaeumle/status/221625197789319168) there is

```
com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier:lower}
```

such that a product name of "Your App" becomes `com.yourcompany.your-app`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I was looking for something to uppercase a variable and :upper apparently works as well (XCode 8.2.1).

Answer (score 4):

```
$ strings /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsCore

PRODUCTNAME
PRODUCTNAMEASIDENTIFIER
PRODUCTNAMEASRFC1034IDENTIFIER
PRODUCTNAMEASXML
```

It seems that there are :identifier, :rfc1034identifier and :xml modifiers. But I have no clue except this.

Comment: It seems sad that we'd have to resort to forensics to get clues. I think I will have to file a bug with apple.

Comment: But, why do you want to know about such modifiers? I have never seen any modifiers except PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier and PRODUCT_NAME:identifier.

Comment: I want to know what they are defined to do. Undocumented "features" are fragile in my mind. Maybe they'll be supported, maybe they'll be stable, maybe not.

Answer (score 2):

After stumbling over this question and its existing answers, I have to say: Apples documentation did not improve on this topic over the recent years. We are currently at Xcode 13 and there is **still no complete list of all modifiers** available.

Therefore I did some spelunking and found the supported modifiers in `DVTFoundation.framework` which I will list below.

I've tested them all in Xcode 13.3 build settings and used the following two macros to illustrate their impact:

```
MY_MACRO = Some "text" with umlauts äöüçñ and special characters are ',/|\-_:;%&<>.!
MY_SOURCE = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/../SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework
```

### Retrieval operators/modifiers

Retrieval modifiers are used to extract and/or transform all or parts of a macro/variable/setting.
They are applied using the following syntax: `$(<VARIABLE>:<MODIFIER>)`

- `quote`: Escapes all characters which have a special meaning in shell scripts/commands like space, colon, semicolon and backslash.

```
RESULT_quote = $(MY_MACRO:quote)

Some\ \"text\"\ with\ umlauts\ äöüçñ\ and\ special\ characters\ are\ \',/|\\-_:;%&<>.!
```

- `upper`: Transforms all characters to their uppercase equivalents.

```
RESULT_upper = $(MY_MACRO:upper)

SOME "TEXT" WITH UMLAUTS ÄÖÜÇÑ AND SPECIAL CHARACTERS ARE ',/|\-_:;%&<>.!
```

- `lower`: Transforms all characters to their lowercase equivalents.

```
RESULT_lower = $(MY_MACRO:lower)

some "text" with umlauts äöüçñ and special characters are ',/|\-_:;%&<>.!
```

- `identifier`: Replaces any non-C identifier characters with an underscore (_).

```
RESULT_identifier = $(MY_MACRO:identifier)

Some__text__with_umlauts_______and_special_characters_are________________
```

- `rfc1034identifier`: Replaces any non-rfc1034 identifier characters with a hyphen (-)

```
RESULT_rfc1034identifier = $(MY_MACRO:rfc1034identifier)


Some--text--with-umlauts-------and-special-characters-are----------------------------
```

- `c99extidentifier`: Replaces any non-C99 identifier characters with an underscore (_). Umlauts are allowed as C99 uses Unicode!

```
RESULT_c99extidentifier = $(MY_MACRO:c99extidentifier)

Some__text__with_umlauts_äöüçñ_and_special_characters_are___________________________
```

- `xml`: According to Apple documentation it should replace special xml characters with the corresponding escape string. For example, less-than (<) is replaced with <. **But in my examples this didn't work**.

```
RESULT_xml = $(MY_MACRO:xml)

Some "text" with umlauts äöüçñ and special characters are ',/|\-_:;%&<>.!
```

- `dir`: Extracts the directory part of a path

```
RESULT_dir = $(MY_SOURCE:dir)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/../SharedFrameworks/
```

- `file`: Extracts the filename part of a path

```
RESULT_file = $(MY_SOURCE:file)

DVTFoundation.framework
```

- `base`: Extracts the filename base part of a path (=filename without suffix/extension)

```
RESULT_base = $(MY_SOURCE:base)

DVTFoundation
```

- `suffix`: Extracts the filename extension/suffix a path or filename

```
RESULT_suffix = $(MY_SOURCE:suffix)

.framework
```

- `standardizepath`: Standardizes the path (e.g. `../` and tilde (~) are resolved)

```
RESULT_standardizepath = $(MY_SOURCE:standardizepath)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework
```

### Replacement operators/modifiers

Beside above extracting/transforming operators, there is support built into the build settings system to replace specific parts of a directory which are matched using a modifier.
They are applied using the following syntax: `$(<VARIABLE>:<MODIFIER>=<VALUE>)`

- `dir=<VALUE>`: Replaces the directory part of a path with `<VALUE>` and returns the new path

```
RESULT2_dir = $(MY_SOURCE:dir=/Developer/SharedFrameworks)

/Developer/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework
```

- `file=<VALUE>`: Replaces the filename part of a path and returns the new path

```
RESULT2_file = $(MY_SOURCE:file=my_file.txt)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/../SharedFrameworks/my_file.txt
```

- `base=<VALUE>`: Replaces the filename base part of a path (=filename without suffix/extension) and returns the new path

```
RESULT2_base = $(MY_SOURCE:base=Dummy)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/../SharedFrameworks/Dummy.framework
```

- `suffix=<VALUE>`: Replaces the filename extension/suffix a path and returns the new path

```
RESULT2_suffix = $(MY_SOURCE:suffix=.txt)

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/../SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.txt
```

I hope this list will help more people looking at Xcodes build settings and wondering how they can be transformed.