# How to automatically set a lowercase bundle identifier

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have set the App ID in iTunes Connect to be lowercase.
Since App IDs are case sensitive, and must match the Bundle Identifier, I now have to change my Bundle Identifier to be lowercase too.

However, this is set automatically by Xcode, and I only know how to edit the info.plist file with an explicit bundle identifier.

Is it possible to tell Xcode to automatically set the bundle identifier, but transform it case to be lowercase?

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode info.plist build variable ${PRODUCT\_NAME:rfc1034identifier} seems completely undocumented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173472/xcode-info-plist-build-variable-product-namerfc1034identifier-seems-complete)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes. You can use [this trick](https://twitter.com/maxbaeumle/status/221625197789319168) instead of setting the bundle identifier statically:

com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier:lower}