# Codemagic issue with provisioning profile IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, codemagic

I had few successful builds few days ago and I even published new app version!
Today I tried to run it again and when building IOS project on Codemagic I got the following error in "xcode-project use-profiles" step:

```
Completed configuring code signing settings
Did not find matching provisioning profiles for code signing!
Generated options for exporting the project
 - Method: ad-hoc
 - Provisioning Profiles: []
 - Signing Certificate: 
 - Signing Style: manual
 - Team Id: 
Saved export options to /Users/builder/export_options.plist
```

but the step before "Set up signing certificate" was successful

```
Add certificates to keychain /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/29-05-22_m73tdocl.keychain-db
Searching for files matching /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Certificates/*.p12
Add certificate /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Certificates/DISTRIBUTION_W29TD264AN_onqr7_8i.p12 to keychain /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/29-05-22_m73tdocl.keychain-db
1 key imported.
1 certificate imported.
```

my [codemagic.yml](https://pastebin.com/MeLn17aY)

any ideas?

Comment: Here is a build url
https://codemagic.io/app/627a848d2d98fd99c3eca4ea/build/6295308affb945615543ce49

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it after debugging the whole codemagic-cli-tool open source library!

**In short**

Change your release PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in project.pbxproj  from `org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)`
to
`org.reactjs.native.example.myApp` (to match your bundle id)

**Full Answer:**

`Did not find matching provisioning profiles` log is a result of `xcode-project use-profiles` command compering real local bundle_id (like org.reactjs.native.example.myApp) with bundle_id within the provisioning profile that generate from PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER variable in `project.pbxproj` file. 
It could be org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier) as your bundle id (more about it explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468176/should-the-rfc1034identifier-be-removed-from-the-cfbundleidentifier-in-plist-file/2468382#2468382))
In order to solve it, make the following steps:

- Go to appName.xcodeproj -> project.pbxproj
- Find under `Begin XCBuildConfiguration section`  your release section and find PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER
- Change PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER from
  `org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)` to
  `org.reactjs.native.example.myApp` to match your bundle id